# keyboard malfunctioning on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

My keyboard of pc seems repeatedly pressing 7 or 2 by itself on a row of 100 times . It doesn't occur continuosly but occurs repeatedly . Please tell me a for  fixing the issue .

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is buy a new keyboard, since they are relatively inexpensive.

Try using computer cleaner and blow the debris from the keyboard. You could even take the keyboard outside and shake it to get rid of dirt/debris.

Other than that you will have to clean it which will be a pain and easier to just buy another keyboard. You can remove those problem keys '7' and '2' and check if there is anything causing the problem. Then get a small bristle or Q-tip try to clean with small amount with alcohol. Put the keys back on and give it a try. Please only try this while there is no power.